# express body-parser and multer value receiving issue?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, body-parser

I am giving post request `/product/create` with some value and an image.

if I console every value before

```
upload(req, res, (err) => {})
```

it is showing properly with out image info.

if I receive the value after `upload(req, res, (err) => {})`

No value is showing.

Full post request code:

```
  app.post('/product/create', (req, res) => {
      let filename;
      upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if(err){
          res.render('index', {
            msg: err
          });
        } else {
          if(req.file == undefined){
            res.render('index', {
              msg: 'Error: No File Selected!'
            });
          } else {
            res.render('index', {
              msg: 'File Uploaded!',
              filename = req.file.filename;
            });
          }
        }
      });

      const product = {
        title : req.body.title,
        desc  : req.body.desc,
        image  : filename,
      }
    });
```

configuring Multer:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});


const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits:{fileSize: 1000000},
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
}).single('myImage');


function checkFileType(file, cb){

  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;

  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null,true);
  } else {
    cb('Error: Images Only!');
  }
}
```

Comment: What is client code for upload, you need to create formData while making request.

Comment: share your multer config code too

Comment: if I console the imagename, mimetype into  upload its showing correctly but when trying get the image value and other value out of upload (req, res) it getting no value. >>> although I am sharing the uploading code.. see update

Answer (score -2):

Multer does not support 'req.file.filename' outside upload function. As filename, originalname, fieldname etc is inbuild API of multer. It is limited to upload function only.

Now, if you are trying to upload product values inside database then you have to create an insert function inside multer upload function only.